# Set environment variable containing at symbol

Tags: windows-7, command-line, proxy, environment-variables, authentication

I would like to set an environment variable containing the URL of my proxy server with my credentials, as in this [blog post](http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2013/03/15/using-gitcomposer-on-windows-7-via-an-authenticated-proxy-server/).

The problem I'm having is that my password contains an at symbol and I am not sure how to properly escape it:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:p@assword@proxy.yourdomain.com:8080
```

How do I do this?

By the way, I realize setting an environment variable containing my credentials is a Very Bad Idea. I'm open to other suggestions that would allow me to use composer behind an authenticated proxy if anyone has one.

Comment: You haven't made it clear that you're talking about **URI** "escaping", not **command interpreter** escaping.  Which is why you're getting these answers about command interpreter escaping.

Comment: Sorry, I meant URI escaping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:p^%40assword@proxy.yourdomain.com:8080
```

1. One needs to [*percent encode*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) the `@` in the password as `%40`, because `@` is a delimiter.
2. One needs to *escape* the `%` in the `set` command so that the command interpreter doesn't even attempt to perform environment variable substitution.  The `^` character as an escape character is a convention that has been around from as far back as IBM's/Microsoft's `cmd` for OS/2 1.x, and that is supported in Microsoft's `cmd` on Windows NT — [as well as in command interpreters such as TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com/help/escape.htm) — to this day.

Answer (score 4):

Special characters can be escaped with "^" on the Windows CMD Shell. So:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:p^@assword^@proxy.yourdomain.com:8080
```

would be outputted as:

```
C:\>echo %HTTP_PROXY%
http://username:p@assword@proxy.yourdomain.com:8080
```

on the shell. But that depends on the tool that is using the variable, I don't know for sure if git takes this as input correctly (but I think so).

Comment: I guess what I'm confused about is how it can tell the difference between the first at sign and the second, or does it not matter?

Comment: It does not matter, the '^' just escapes the following character. Every time - so ^^.^^ will work too (output: ^.^).

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out having a '%' is an even worse nightmare, as you have to escape it to '^%%' in your *.cmd* file

say, `set http_proxy=https://my-user-name:woops-my-password-contains-^%%@windows.sucks.com:8080`

```
>echo %http_proxy%
http_proxy=https://my-user-name:woops-my-password-contains-%@windows.sucks.com:8080
```